# Regarding eclipse libraries

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, java

Have a question on eclipse libraries. I have an eclipse java project where I have created a library which contains some 50 odd jars files which are needed by the project. Now I have created a new project where I need the library. A very cumbersome way to do this is to check all the jar files in that library, them create a new library in my current project where I will manually add all the 50 odd jars. Is there a way I can export the library from my old project to the current project so that I can have all the requisite jars in one shot.

Regards,
   Dev

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can export the lib.

refer to the screen shot
[image]

Just select the Lib you want to export , then select export button

Enter the path where you want to store the export file

[image]

Now to import,  go the the same place and select the import option

Select the import file and click ok

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer,, But I still have a slight issue here. Actually the library is not a user library but from Maven dependencies library in which some other third party jars have been manually added. So I am not seeing it in the User libraries tab. So is there a way to create a user library having the same jars as the modified maven library and then export it as you have told just now...Once thanks for your help.

Comment: @user496934 : your question no where suggests anything about Maven. First Improve your question.

Comment: I think my question is succinct, basically it is to export a system library not a user library. But ill explain more. The first project is a maven project, where I have edited the pom file and updated maven in eclipse which automatically modifies the maven library with the dependant jars in the maven library. So for the first project I have a lot of dependant jar files in maven library. Now I have created another maven project and I want the maven library of the new project to contain the same jars as the previous maven library .  Is it possible to do it other than manually ?